# Word Sense Disambiguation for Arabic text with NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, arabic, word-sense-disambiguation

NLTK allows me to disambiguate text with `nltk.wsd.lesk`, e.g.

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> from nltk.wsd import lesk
>>> sent = "I went to the bank to deposit money"
>>> ambiguous = "deposit"
>>> lesk(sent, ambiguous, pos='v')
Synset('deposit.v.02')
```

[`PyWSD`](https://github.com/alvations/pywsd) does the same but it's only for English text.

---

NLTK supports arabic wordnet from the [Open Multilingual WordNet](http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/omw/), e.g.

```
>>> wn.synsets('deposit', pos='v')[1].lemma_names(lang='arb')
[u'\u0623\u064e\u0648\u0652\u062f\u064e\u0639\u064e']
>>> print wn.synsets('deposit', pos='v')[1].lemma_names(lang='arb')[0]
أَوْدَعَ
```

Also, the synsets are indexed for Arabic:

```
>>> wn.synsets(u'أَوْدَعَ', lang='arb')
[Synset('entrust.v.02'), Synset('deposit.v.02'), Synset('commit.v.03'), Synset('entrust.v.01'), Synset('consign.v.02')]
```

But how could i disambiguate Arabic texts and extract concepts from a query using nltk?

I was wondering if it is possible to use Lesk algorithm to deal with Arabic texts through nltk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little tricky but maybe this will work:

1. Translate the sentence and the ambiguous word
2. Use lesk on the English version of the sentence

Try:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ wget -O translate.sh http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=aHgFzmMU
--2015-08-05 23:32:46--  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=aHgFzmMU
Resolving pastebin.com (pastebin.com)... 190.93.241.15, 190.93.240.15, 141.101.112.16, ...
Connecting to pastebin.com (pastebin.com)|190.93.241.15|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘translate.sh’

    [ <=>                                                                                                                            ] 212         --.-K/s   in 0s      

2015-08-05 23:32:47 (9.99 MB/s) - ‘translate.sh’ saved [212]

alvas@ubi:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> text = 'لديه يودع المال في البنك'
>>> cmd = 'echo "{}" | bash translate.sh'.format(text)
>>> translation = os.popen(cmd).read()
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   193    0    40  100   153     21     83  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--    83
>>> translation
'He has deposited the money in the bank. '
>>> ambiguous = u'أَوْدَعَ'
>>> wn.synsets(ambiguous, lang='arb')
[Synset('entrust.v.02'), Synset('deposit.v.02'), Synset('commit.v.03'), Synset('entrust.v.01'), Synset('consign.v.02')]
>>> nltk.wsd.lesk(translation_stems, '', synsets=wn.synsets(ambiguous,lang='arb'))
Synset('entrust.v.02')
```

But as you can see, there are many limitations:

- Access to an MT system is not always easy  (The above bash script using IBM API that will not last forever, it came from https://github.com/Rich-Edwards/fsharpwatson/blob/master/Command%20Line%20CURL%20Scripts)
- Machine Translation will never be 100% accurate
- Looking for the correct lemma in the Open Multilingual WordNet is not as easy as shown in the example, there's inflection and other morphemic variants to a stem.
- WordNet is never complete, especially when it's the not English.
- WSD is not 100% as human expected (Even between humans we vary our "senses", in the example above, some might say the WSD is right, some say it's better to use `Synset('deposit.v.02')`)

Comment: Hello Alvas, i need to know from you if above translation api is still working or else anything else you can recommend